# CSS Selector - first element with Class in a group of same class

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I have a list of elements under the same container. some of them has class **A**, other has class **B**.
I'm looking for a CSS selector to select the first A element in a group of A and the first B element in a group of B.

Example:

```html
    <style>
    .A { background: red; }
    .B { background: blue; }
    </style>
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="item A">AAA</li><!-- I want to select this -->
      <li class="item A">aaa</li>
      <li class="item A">aaa</li>
      <li class="item B">BBB</li><!-- I want to select this -->
      <li class="item B">bbb</li>
      <li class="item B">bbb</li>
      <li class="item A">AAA</li><!-- I want to select this -->
      <li class="item A">aaa</li>
      <li class="item A">aaa</li>
    </ul>
```

Notice that using the pseudo selector `:first-of-type` will not work, becuase it will select the first element of type without group relation.

Also trying to use `:first-child` will not work ether, since it will select only the first A element, and will not select the first B element, also it will not select the first A element in the 2nd group.

#### Note

I don't believe this is a duplicate of "[CSS selector for first element with class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class)".

Comment: @Rob, I think you don't understand my question. No `first-child` will **not** work! I'm not trying to select the first child, I looking for a selector to select the first element in a group of elements. In the example you can see that I want to select the first B item. using `first-child` will not work!

Comment: `first-child` will only select first child of `ul` element.

Comment: You are right. I misunderstood.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To select first child of the `ul` element, you can use `:first-child` pseudo-class.

To select the first element in each group, you can use [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator).

`.A + .B` will select any element with class `B` that immediately follows an element with class `A`. Similarly `.B + .A` will select any element with class `A` that immediately follows an element with class `B`

```css
.A { background: red; }
.B { background: blue; }

.A:first-child,
.B + .A,
.A + .B {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="item A">AAA</li><!-- I want to select this -->
  <li class="item A">AAA</li>
  <li class="item A">AAA</li>
  <li class="item B">BBB</li><!-- I want to select this -->
  <li class="item B">BBB</li>
  <li class="item B">BBB</li>
  <li class="item A">AAA</li><!-- I want to select this -->
  <li class="item A">AAA</li>
  <li class="item A">AAA</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Wow, amazing. Can you please explain this `.B + .A` and this `.A + .B`

Answer (score 0):

In case you didn't know what's each class name (for example, when scraping) you could use JS to find groups that match your criteria:

```js
let list = document.querySelector('.list');


let filtered = [...list.children].filter((item) => {
  let previous = item.previousElementSibling;
  return !previous || [...previous.classList].join('.') !== [...item.classList].join('.');
});

console.log(filtered);
```

```css
.A {
  background: red;
}

.B {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="item A">First AAA</li>
  <!-- I want to select this -->
  <li class="item A">AAA</li>
  <li class="item A">AAA</li>
  <li class="item B">First BBB</li>
  <!-- I want to select this -->
  <li class="item B">BBB</li>
  <li class="item B">BBB</li>
  <li class="item A">Second AAA</li>
  <!-- I want to select this -->
  <li class="item A">AAA</li>
  <li class="item A">AAA</li>
</ul>
```

You could also restrict your criteria to groups of elements that share their tagName.

Comment: With JavaScript you can do beautiful things, but my question was about pure Css